# What is this purpose of this function?

Tags: javascript, string, function, encryption, hash

I have been looking for an encryption key for a certain website  and i came across this function . I was wondering What does this function do or even means?

```
this.GetUserDirectory = function () {
var PJWHashText = function (pTextToHash) {
    var ascii = "01234567890123456789012345678901" + " !\"#i%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + "[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
    var gg = 0;
    var hh = 0;
    var ch, val;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < pTextToHash.length; ii++) {
        ch = pTextToHash.charAt(ii);
        val = (((ch > '#') && (ch < '%')) ? 36 : ascii.lastIndexOf(ch));
        hh = (hh << 4) + val;
        gg = hh & 0xF0000000;
        if (gg != 0) {
            hh = hh ^ (gg >>> 24);
            hh = hh ^ gg;
        }
    }
    return hh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an elaborate function that generates a hash (in this case a number) of a string (the `pTextToHash` argument). Such a hash can be used in other functions (for example in a hashmap-like datastructure).

The inner workings involve:

- translating every chacarter in the string to a number
- some
  interesting bitshifting and logical processing to allow these numbers
  to be merged into some composite number without destroying the
  previous numbers in that composite number.

One important property of this function is that the same input always returns the same output.

Comment: Can these generated hash be cracked? if so how? and also Where would you suggest looking for an encryption key on a 2d game .

Comment: a hash is not something you crack.. It's a one way algorithm and you cannot find the input string based on the output if that is what you mean. Also: I have no idea about your other question:-)

Comment: ok  , theres a site i can log cookies from but inorder to use them , They got to be decoded and rehashed. A guy who also knows how to log cookies from the same site , told me how to inject them to gain access He told me ( the way i just stated ) . He said i should look in the JS files for the encryption key to crack the hash. I also believe him because he access my account before VIA teamviewer with cookies. Idk where is this js files because i checked every page on the site and only found the function in the question..

Comment: oh, I do suppose it's technically possible to write some program that generates (or finds) input strings that would produce a given output number, but that could be quite a puzzle (or at least a new question;-)